# Why is this read blocking when O_NONBLOCK is set?

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

Strace excerpt (please ignore sending xml to ssh):

```
dup(12)                                 = 13
getsockname(13, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(46811), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, [1], [4]) = 0
fstat(13, {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0777, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getsockname(13, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(46811), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, [1], [4]) = 0
fcntl(13, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
fcntl(13, F_GETFL)                      = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [0], 4) = 0
setsockopt(13, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [0], 4) = 0
setsockopt(13, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [0], 4) = 0
fcntl(12, F_GETFL)                      = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)              = 0
close(12)                               = 0
getpeername(13, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(22), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
sendto(13, "<stream:stream xmlns:stream='htt"..., 133, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 133
read(13, "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1\r\n", 4096) = 23
read(13,  <unfinished ...>
```

(At the end I kill -9 it.)

The `read()` at the end was blocking; even though `O_NONBLOCK` was set via `fcntl()`.

How is this possible?

---

Version info:

```
$ uname -r
3.16.4-1-ARCH
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because FD 13 is a `dup()` of FD 12, this line removes your `O_NONBLOCK`:

```
fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)              = 0
```